The Maximum Size of a Theoretical Dyson Sphere
In the paper "Dyson spheres around white dwarfs" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04376) it clearly states on page 11 that the bonds required for making such an object are in the order of $\times10^{13}\frac{N}{m^2}$ for white dwarfs & this makes them impossible because the theoretical maximum perpendicular force chemical bonds can hold is $\times10^{11}N$.
But the paper still gives us the equation for rigid Dyson spheres
$$S=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{GM}{2r}\rho$$ $$S=Stress\\F=Force\\A=Area\\G=Gravitational\;Constant=6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^2}\\r=radius\\ \rho=density(shell)\\M=Mass(central\;body)$$
If we plug in the maximum force of $\times10^{11}N$ as the maximum
Instead of white dwarf level of masses, lets assume planet masses & crunch them down to smaller radii. example: Earth has a mass of $5.972\times10^{24}kg$ in lieu of the white dwarf or other star mass.
Assuming a shell density more comparable to normal matter you'd expect on a surface so $\rho=1500\frac{kg}{m^3}$ to $\rho=3500\frac{kg}{m^3}$
Using algebra the equation to find applicable radii would be
$$\frac{GM\rho}{2S}=r$$
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(1500\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{11}N)}=3000km$$
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(3500\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{11}N)}=7000km$$
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(5000\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{11}N)}=10000km$$
If you assume a safety factor reducing the stress to $\times10^{10}$ then you end up with
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(1500\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{10}N)}=30000km$$
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(3500\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{10}N)}=70000km$$
$$\frac{(6.67\times10^{-11}\frac{N\cdot m^2}{kg^3})(6\times10^{24}kg)(5000\frac{kg}{m^3})}{(2)(1\times10^{10}N)}=100000km$$
In other words each order of magnitude away from the theoretical maximum stress limit of matter for safety adds an order of magnitude onto the required radius. The same becomes true for the mass of the central body, each order of magnitude you reduce your central mass decreases the required radius by an equal factor.
Is this accurate to describe the physical limits of Dyson Spheres that could be designed?
AU sizes impossible, planet sizes possible.

It's inaccurate. At these scales, architectures that depend on the strength or rigidity limits of materials should be dismissed early on.
A Dyson Sphere needs artificial gravity. Sticking with known physics, a number of wide, magnetically levitated tracks traveling around the sun on stationary roadbeds is one way to avoid material strength limits and provide artificial gravity. The combined momentum of the track and the roadbed must be designed to be equivalent to an orbiting ring of the same diameter and mass. People living on the inner side of the moving track will circle the sun at faster than orbital velocity and experience artificial gravity.
You can, of course, construct a sphere by building many such rings at many different orientations.
A Dyson "sphere" is really just what such a megaproject might look like from far away. In practice it is more likely to be a large number of orbiting satellites (a Dyson swarm) or a collection of magnetically levitated rings on stationary roadbeds at many different orientations.

Is the calculation off? Is the original equation of the paper off? Otherwise why are you focusing on sun sizes when we both know those are impossible? The math has long since said as much. I'm strictly asking about the size parameters that don't require breaking known physics. Building a sphere like this out of astroids could be useful within the next 2 centuries for building basic space habitats.

The question asks "Is this [math] accurate to describe the physical limits of Dyson Spheres that could be designed?" The correct answer is that it is not accurate because the math analyzes a specific design - the rigid Dyson's sphere. There are better designs that are not analyzed by this math.
